# Selecting 3 tables using JOIN but cant select 4?

Tags: php, mysql

So pretty much with my SQL `SELECT` query i can see the answer when i have 3 tables joined but when i try and join the final 4th table i get '0 Results' message? here is the 3 table query:

```
$sql = "SELECT paymentPersonal.custID as paymentPersonalCust, paymentPersonal.firstname as paymentPersonalFname, paymentPersonal.lastname as paymentPersonalLname, paymentPersonal.mobile as paymentPersonalMobile, paymentPersonal.homephone as paymentPersonalHphone, paymentPersonal.email as paymentPersonalEmail, paymentsPayment.custID as paymentsPaymentCust, paymentsPayment.nameoncard as paymentsPaymentname, paymentsPayment.ccnumber as paymentsPaymentNumber, paymentsPayment.year as paymentsPaymentYear, paymentsPayment.month as paymentsPaymentMonth, paymentsPayment.code as paymentsPaymentCode, paymentsProduct.custID as paymentsProductCust, paymentsProduct.product as paymentsProduct from paymentPersonal join paymentsPayment on paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID join paymentsProduct on paymentPersonal.custID = paymentsProduct.custID where paymentPersonal.custID='$custID'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result != null) 
{
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentPersonalCust"]. " - FirstName: ". $row["paymentPersonalFname"]. " - LastName: " . $row["paymentPersonalLname"] .  " - Mobile: ". $row["paymentPersonalMobile"]. " - Homephone: ". $row["paymentPersonalHphone"]. " - Email: ". $row["paymentPersonalEmail"]."<br>";

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentsPaymentCust"]. " - CcName: ". $row["paymentsPaymentname"]. " - CcNumber:  " . $row["paymentsPaymentNumber"] .  " - ccYear: ". $row["paymentsPaymentYear"]. " - ccMonth: ". $row["paymentsPaymentMonth"]. " - ccCode: ". $row["paymentsPaymentCode"]."<br>";

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentsProductCust"]. " - Product: ". $row["paymentsProduct"]."<br>";

     }
}

else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

Which DOES work and displays all of the data id expect BUT when I add the 4th table it doesnt work anymore and get the `else echo; "0results"`. This is the 4 table result that i have added:

```
$sql = "SELECT paymentPersonal.custID as paymentPersonalCust, paymentPersonal.firstname as paymentPersonalFname, paymentPersonal.lastname as paymentPersonalLname, paymentPersonal.mobile as paymentPersonalMobile, paymentPersonal.homephone as paymentPersonalHphone, paymentPersonal.email as paymentPersonalEmail, paymentsPayment.custID as paymentsPaymentCust, paymentsPayment.nameoncard as paymentsPaymentname, paymentsPayment.ccnumber as paymentsPaymentNumber, paymentsPayment.year as paymentsPaymentYear, paymentsPayment.month as paymentsPaymentMonth, paymentsPayment.code as paymentsPaymentCode, paymentsProduct.custID as paymentsProductCust, paymentsProduct.product as paymentsProduct, paymentsShipping.custID as paymentsShippingCust, paymentsShipping.address as paymentsShippingAddress, paymentsShipping.region as paymentsShippingRegion, paymentsShipping.city as paymentsShippingCity, paymentsShipping.postcode as paymentsShippingPostcode from paymentPersonal join paymentsPayment on paymentsPayment.custID = paymentPersonal.custID join paymentsProduct on paymentPersonal.custID = paymentsProduct.custID join paymentsShipping on paymentsShipping.custID = paymentsPayment.custID where paymentPersonal.custID='$custID'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result != null) 
{
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentPersonalCust"]. " - FirstName: ". $row["paymentPersonalFname"]. " - LastName: " . $row["paymentPersonalLname"] .  " - Mobile: ". $row["paymentPersonalMobile"]. " - Homephone: ". $row["paymentPersonalHphone"]. " - Email: ". $row["paymentPersonalEmail"]."<br>";

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentsPaymentCust"]. " - CcName: ". $row["paymentsPaymentname"]. " - CcNumber:  " . $row["paymentsPaymentNumber"] .  " - ccYear: ". $row["paymentsPaymentYear"]. " - ccMonth: ". $row["paymentsPaymentMonth"]. " - ccCode: ". $row["paymentsPaymentCode"]."<br>";

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentsProductCust"]. " - Product: ". $row["paymentsProduct"]."<br>";

        echo "<br> custID: ". $row["paymentPersonalCust"]. " - Address: ". $row["paymentsShippingAddress"]. " - Region: " . $row["paymentsShippingRegion"] .  " - City: ". $row["paymentsShippingCity"]. " - postcode: ". $row["paymentsShippingPostcode"]."<br>"; 
     }
}

else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

im not sure wether its something small im missing or is major?? let me know if you have an idea.. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is valid data in the 4th table? Maybe it should be 0 results with the data there.

Comment: How does it relate to PHP? It doesn't. And how can we know why there're no results if we don't know how the schema and data looks like?

Comment: Do you get any result for `SELECT * FROM paymentsShipping WHERE custID='$custID';`

Comment: only having shipping OR just the other 3 worked, i couldnt mix both and yes there is valid data in the shipping table. and all 4 tables all have the `custID`

Comment: Are you sure your 4th table has data for this customer id? if not the instead of use `join` use 'left join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell what might be going on without a sample of the data, however the first thing I would try is to make the final join a LEFT JOIN instead of a regular JOIN.   With a regular JOIN data needs to exist on on both sides of the join where with a left join data only needs to exist in the source table.

In fact I would probably recommend making them all left joins if you think there is a good chance some of your tables will not have data.  For example you know you have a customer but maybe they do not have a phone number in your contact table.  With a regular join you would not be able to see your customer until a phone number existed which is probably not desirable.

Finally, when making left joins be prepared for certain columns to be NULL.

Comment: found the error, it was missing a comma between one of the table Columbus.

Comment: Awesome, good eye!  Those missing comma's can be hard to see.  Usually, if I have to put SQL in code (which I try to avoid) I will break it up so that those kinds of things are a bit easier to spot.